# Avoid dividing by zero with just variables and basic operators

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, algorithms, computer-science, ratio

I am working on stats for a sports team, and one of the stats I have the ratio of `Shots` and `Shots on Target` (Which I call `SOTP`). So, for instance, if a player has 2 shots, and one's on target, their `SOTP` ratio is 1/2 or 50%.

Now I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. The software that generates the stats lets me put in numbers, variables, or basic operators (`+, -, /, *`, and `**`, which represents `^`). So for the `SOTP` I have $SOTP = SHOTSONTARGET/SHOTS$. My problem arises when a player has zero shots since the denominator is zero. If this is the case, the software automatically returns nothing, which works until I need to use the `SOTP` ratio in another operation. For instance, I have something that generates points based off passes, goals, etc, but when `SOTP` is equal to nothing, the points return nothing, even if the player has points.

So my question is, is there anything I can do to avoid the zero in the denominator by just using basic operators, constants, and variables?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you just set SOTP=-1 when SHOTS=0?

Comment: Check when the denominator is $0$, and set the variable to some special value. That's the standard thing.

Comment: How would I do that? I can only use operators, and not IF() statements, etc. However, I can do $0^0$ and get one. Is there some way I could use that? If I do $SOTP = Shotsontarget/shots^shots$, I get $0$ if shots is zero (since $0/0^0$ somehow equals $0/1$ to the software), but then if shots is two or something, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative solution:

$$
\text{SOTP} = \frac{\text{shots on target}}{\text{shots} + 0^{\text{shots}}}
$$
Also, if you want to set it to be $-1$ when there are no shots (as one of the comments suggested), you could have
$$
\text{SOTP} = \frac{\text{shots on target}-0^{\text{shots}}}{\text{shots} + 0^{\text{shots}}}
$$

Answer (score 5):

That is a strange problem, and I feel like that shouldn't happen.  Also, how can a player have points without having any shots?

Anyway, here's an easy fix:
$$
\text{SOTP} = \frac{\text{shots on target} +.001}{\text{shots} + .001}
$$
This will give you approximately the right answer most of the time, and will give you $1$ when $\text{shots} = 0$.  Instead of $.001$, you could use any sufficiently small value.

Comment: Thanks. That actually works well because the program rounds. The only thing I did differently was this $SOTP = Shots on target/(shots + 0.0001)$ since I need $SOTP$ to be equal to zero if shots is zero. But thanks. That's much easier that what I was trying to do, which was raise $shots$ to the zero if $shots$ was zero, and otherwise raise $shots$ to the one if $shots$ was one or greater (I'd be really impressed if there were some way to do this).

Comment: Oh, btw, a player can have points if they have passes, tackles, etc. :)

Comment: I thought of another solution using the $0^0 = 1$ bit, if you're interested.  See the latest edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now I don't have to worry about the rounding. Wish I could +2 ya! Actually, if you wanted to, it's fine with me if you put that as another answer, since it's not the same as the original.

Comment: Fair enough, and glad to help.