# Turning division by zero to zero with basic math operators

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, ratio

I need to compute $\frac{const}{y}$, where $y$ may equal $0$ to present PC state in a human-readable format from exposed internal registers. Is it possible to build an expression of basic math operators ($+$, $-$, $/$, $($, $)$, $*$, $a^b$, $\ln(a)$) that evaluates to $0$, when $y=0$, and to $\frac{const}{y}$ otherwise? The resulting expression may be as complex as necessary, but may include only the listed operators.

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674535/482449), with a different result as a "fallback" value.

Comment: That is a very strange requirement! What do you need it for?

Comment: Using numeric operations to achieve casewise logic is very inefficient. A computing platform that can do exponentiation and logarithms can certainly do conditional evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674581/482449):
$$\frac{const*(1-0^y)}{y+0^y}$$

Comment: That relies on two conditions: (i) $0^0$ must evaluate to $1$, and (ii) $0/0$ must evaluate to $0$. The first is true for the question in your link, but not on every platform; the second is very unlikely to be true.

Comment: Yes, sorry $-$ I misread the denominator.